# ELKI GUI output and parameter k (LOF)

Tags: data-mining, outliers, elki

I am suspicious about: **Materializing k nearest neighbors (k=3)** in the following output.

Verbose output from ELKI GUI, running LOFalgorithm, **lof.k=2**.

```
LOF #1/3: Materializing LOF neighborhoods.
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.preprocessed.knn.MaterializeKNNPreprocessor.**k: 3**
Materializing k nearest neighbors **(k=3)**: 198 [100%]
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.preprocessed.knn.MaterializeKNNPreprocessor.precomputation-time: 3 ms
LOF #2/3: Computing LRDs.
LOF #3/3: Computing LOFs.
LOF: complete.
```

Does that mean that ELKI looks at points' 3nn, when I set lof.k=2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behaviour.

To compute LOF fast, you need to precompute the k nearest neighbors.

Since the k nearest neighbors in ELKI - as common in a databases - usually *includes* the query point, you need the k+1 nearest neighbors for LOF, to get k *other* points.